# Making my query more efficient

Tags: php, sql, indexing

im currently doing a query that pulls a string from my db. but it has to check for every new row i import. and a file of 100k takes almost 4 hours to import. thats way too long. im assuming that my sql code to check if he exist is the thing slowing it down.
ive heard about indexing but i have no clue what it is or how to use it.

this is the current code im using:

```
$sql2 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM prospects WHERE :ssn = ssn');
$sql2->execute(array(':ssn' => $ssn));
if($sql2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) > 0){
```

so everytime the phpscript reads a new row, it does this check. problem is, that i cant put it in "on duplicate key" in the sql code. it has to check before going to any sql, because if this is empty, then it should continue doing its thing.

what could i do to make this more efficient regarding time? and also, if index is the way to go, could someone enlighten me how this would be done by either posting examples, linking a guide or php.net page. and how i could read from that index to do what i am in my code

Comment: Then perhaps reading a bit about [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html) would be a good place to start

Comment: Indexing a table is not PHP related. Is the `ssn` primary, foreighn key or neither?

Comment: SQL is based around "sets" or collections of rows, and most efficiencies are concentrated around this use case.  Dumping the data into a temporary table db-side and running a query over everything at once may yield better results on the whole.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 100k records and you don't have any index? Start then with creating one

```
CREATE INDEX ssn_index ON prospects (ssn)
```

Now, each time when you try to select something from `prospects` table with `where` condition on `ssn` column MySQL is going to check where it should look for the records by the index. If this column is strongly selective (there are many different values) the query is going to be performed fast.

You can check your execution plan by querying

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM prospects WHERE :ssn = ssn
```

Comment: so say i run that create index, is it there forever? does it update when i add new rows? or do you have to add to the index aswell? do use the sql code the same way?

Comment: Yes, it will be stored forever and auto-updated. If you export your database it will be exported as well.

Comment: thanks, ive added an index key to ssn in that table. however, the query doesnt feel faster at all. do i still write the same sql code or do i alter it somehow?

Comment: Please provide us the results of execution plan.